# Get the requesting url with QHttpServer

Tags: c++, qt, http, network-programming

Below is a simple example of using QHttpServer.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtHttpServer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QHttpServer httpServer;
    httpServer.route("/", []() {
        return "Hello world";
    });
    httpServer.route("/test/", []() {
        return "test";
    });

    httpServer.afterRequest([](QHttpServerResponse &&resp) {
        resp.setHeader("Server", "Super server!");
        return std::move(resp);
    });

    const auto port = httpServer.listen(QHostAddress::Any);
    if (!port) {
        qDebug() << QCoreApplication::translate(
                "QHttpServerExample", "Server failed to listen on a port.");
        return 0;
    }

    qDebug() << QCoreApplication::translate(
            "QHttpServerExample", "Running on http://127.0.0.1:%1/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)").arg(port);

    return app.exec();
}
```

After runing the code, you can input urls of below in a broswer,

http://127.0.0.1:port

> Hello world

http://127.0.0.1:port/test

> test

My purpose is to catch all requests in one function -- even with arbitrary sub urls, like

> http://127.0.0.1:port/abc

> http://127.0.0.1:port/zzz/test/123123

And how do I get these urls?

I asked AI about it. It points to `QHttpRequest`, but I don't have such thing in my Qt lib. And I also checked it on Qt document, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you looked at [`QHttpServerRequest::url`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qhttpserverrequest.html#url)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @m7913d's reminding. I find this,

```
server.setMissingHandler([](const QHttpServerRequest& request,
    QHttpServerResponder&& responder) {
        request.url();
    });
```